# Forcing WWW with httpd.conf rather than .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I've read up on many Force WWW. tricks using htaccess. (As Below)

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domina.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm wondering if there is a method to force WWW using httpd.config across the entire site.

The htaccess works a treat, but I have many subdirectories, most of them include there own .htacess files, which breaks the force www in that particular subdirectory.

So I was thinking, is there a way to force this "www." into httpd.config, across the entire site without editing .htaccess?

Thanks.

Comment: Why downvotes with no comment? This was helpful to me, 5 years later...

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And to maintain HTTPS too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That works for all the files in my Site Root, but does not hold true to sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
# direct all variation of FQDN to www.epoch.co.il
  RewriteEngine on

  #RewriteLogLevel 3
  #RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/epoch/www/epoch-rewrite_log"

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.epoch\.co\.il [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.epoch.co.il/$1 [L,R]
```