# How can I use httpd.conf to force www

Tags: apache, configuration

I am trying to force the www. in the beginning of my domain...
I am aware of using the method mentioned on the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509113/forcing-www-with-httpd-conf-rather-than-htaccess) to do this in the httpd.conf file, but this causes Apache to say that it doesn't understand this command. Is there something I am doing wrong... or do I need to put the code in a certain spot?
-Thanks, San

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? and what are the rewrite rules that you tried? Also please include any error logs that you see which is relevant to this.

Comment: Error is "Syntax Error on line 2 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid command 'ReWrite Engine", perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.", and rules are RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]